# spring-boot Reactor java.lang.ClassNotFoundException MultiReaderFastList

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I just downloaded the spring-boot Reactor getting started guide from [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-reactor/). I navigate to the complete directory, run mvn package without issue and then mvn spring-boot:run fails with the root problem being **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gs.collections.impl.list.mutable.MultiReaderFastList**

I don't see why I'm getting this error since this jar seems to be in my path **/home/steven/.m2/repository/com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/5.0.0/gs-collections-5.0.0.jar**

Any thoughts?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gs-messaging-reactor 0.2.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ gs-messaging-reactor >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gs-messaging-reactor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/steven/sublime-workspace/gs-messaging-reactor-master/complete/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/steven/sublime-workspace/gs-messaging-reactor-master/complete/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gs-messaging-reactor ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ gs-messaging-reactor ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/steven/sublime-workspace/gs-messaging-reactor-master/complete/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gs-messaging-reactor ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ gs-messaging-reactor <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ gs-messaging-reactor ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.5.RELEASE)

2014-08-26 19:09:14.494  INFO 11729 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on myhostname with PID 11729 (/home/steven/sublime-workspace/gs-messaging-reactor-master/complete/target/classes started by steven.zgaljic in /home/steven/sublime-workspace/gs-messaging-reactor-master/complete)
2014-08-26 19:09:14.520  INFO 11729 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@68de462: startup date [Tue Aug 26 19:09:14 GMT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-08-26 19:09:14.883  INFO 11729 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/steven/sublime-workspace/gs-messaging-reactor-master/complete/src/main/resources, file:/home/steven/sublime-workspace/gs-messaging-reactor-master/complete/src/main/resources, file:/home/steven/sublime-workspace/gs-messaging-reactor-master/complete/target/classes/, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/com/lmax/disruptor/3.2.1/disruptor-3.2.1.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/5.0.0/gs-collections-5.0.0.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/1.2/json-smart-1.2.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/projectreactor/reactor-core/1.1.2.RELEASE/reactor-core-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-core/1.1.2.RELEASE/reactor-spring-core-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/0.9.1/json-path-0.9.1.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/com/goldmansachs/gs-collections-api/5.0.0/gs-collections-api-5.0.0.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/projectreactor/spring/reactor-spring-context/1.1.2.RELEASE/reactor-spring-context-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.3.3/jackson-annotations-2.3.3.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.3.3/jackson-core-2.3.3.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.3.3/jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar, file:/home/steven/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.2/logback-core-1.1.2.jar]
2014-08-26 19:09:14.884  INFO 11729 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2014-08-26 19:09:14.887 ERROR 11729 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.reactor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createReactor' defined in class hello.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.createReactor(reactor.core.Environment)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:63)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.reactor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createReactor' defined in class hello.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.createReactor(reactor.core.Environment)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createReactor' defined in class hello.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.createReactor(reactor.core.Environment)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.createReactor(reactor.core.Environment)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at reactor.event.registry.CachingRegistry.<init>(CachingRegistry.java:43)
    at reactor.event.registry.CachingRegistry.<init>(CachingRegistry.java:37)
    at reactor.core.spec.support.EventRoutingComponentSpec.createRegistry(EventRoutingComponentSpec.java:272)
    at reactor.core.spec.support.EventRoutingComponentSpec.createReactor(EventRoutingComponentSpec.java:239)
    at reactor.core.spec.support.EventRoutingComponentSpec.configure(EventRoutingComponentSpec.java:232)
    at reactor.core.spec.support.DispatcherComponentSpec.get(DispatcherComponentSpec.java:157)
    at hello.Application.createReactor(Application.java:31)
    at hello.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d637dd.CGLIB$createReactor$2(<generated>)
    at hello.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d637dd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b609127.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at hello.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d637dd.createReactor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gs.collections.impl.list.mutable.MultiReaderFastList
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 47 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.reactor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createReactor' defined in class hello.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.createReactor(reactor.core.Environment)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:63)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.reactor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createReactor' defined in class hello.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.createReactor(reactor.core.Environment)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createReactor' defined in class hello.Application: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.createReactor(reactor.core.Environment)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [reactor.core.Reactor hello.Application.createReactor(reactor.core.Environment)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gs/collections/impl/list/mutable/MultiReaderFastList
    at reactor.event.registry.CachingRegistry.<init>(CachingRegistry.java:43)
    at reactor.event.registry.CachingRegistry.<init>(CachingRegistry.java:37)
    at reactor.core.spec.support.EventRoutingComponentSpec.createRegistry(EventRoutingComponentSpec.java:272)
    at reactor.core.spec.support.EventRoutingComponentSpec.createReactor(EventRoutingComponentSpec.java:239)
    at reactor.core.spec.support.EventRoutingComponentSpec.configure(EventRoutingComponentSpec.java:232)
    at reactor.core.spec.support.DispatcherComponentSpec.get(DispatcherComponentSpec.java:157)
    at hello.Application.createReactor(Application.java:31)
    at hello.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d637dd.CGLIB$createReactor$2(<generated>)
    at hello.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d637dd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7b609127.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at hello.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0d637dd.createReactor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gs.collections.impl.list.mutable.MultiReaderFastList
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 47 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.100 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-08-26T19:09:14+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/300M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is the jar file readable? Sometimes it's worth deleting the local cache and re-running the app.

Comment: Nice, deleting my entire repository worked like a charm!

Comment: By the way, the jar was readable even before I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my entire maven repository and it worked. I suppose you could delete just the library in question.